# XML string to file .xml

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I'm trying to save my xml string into a xml file using Node.js fs module. After the saving I'm able to open the file using notepad, but if I try open on Internet explorer (The browser show a formatted xml) the result it's not a xml file.

How can I save my string to a valid XML file?

```
//My string: str_xml = "<NFEPROC VERSAO=\"4.00\" XMLNS=\"HTTP://WWW.PORTALFISCAL.INF.BR/NFE\">...</NFEPROC>"

//save process:
fs.writeFileSync( current_dir + '/NF ' + doc[i].number + '.xml',doc[i].xml)

//Notepad output:
<NFEPROC VERSAO=\"4.00\" XMLNS=\"HTTP://WWW.PORTALFISCAL.INF.BR/NFE\">...</NFEPROC>

//IE output:
3372127450VENDA65712018-11-09T12:24:19-02:0011330240341211110PYNFE 0.430725442000166G.S. ... .000.010010.0001020.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.010.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.010.009010.01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my problem. The mongoDB model was setted as Uppercase in this attribute. When I mount de XML file with upper case tags, the pattern of my xml files was lost.

On this first moment I solved like this:

```
fs.writeFileSync( current_dir + '/NF ' + doc[i].number + '.xml', doc[i].xml.toLowerCase())
```